# What scope should I use when calling a suspended function from a Java Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm calling a suspend function from `Activity` written in `Java`.  Right now I'm using `EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE` as the return of the `getContext()` method of my `Continuation`. Is that the right `CoroutineContext`? will that lead to issues if the suspended function finishes after my `Activity` has gone away?

Thanks.

Comment: Here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines you can find some useful info about coroutines and also here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTDXo0-SKuU is one of the best video for coroutines.

Comment: You should never call a coroutine function from Java.  At most, you should write a non coroutine function from Kotlin to launch the coroutine.

Answer (score 3):

I can propose an alternate solution. If you can't modify your Activity, you could consider creating a delegate in Kotlin that you offload the calling of that suspending function to. In the delegate you could then access the `lifecycleScope` of the Activity and use that for the call.

```
class MyDelegage(private val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) {

    fun doWorkAsync() {
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            suspendFunHere()
        }
    }
}
```

then you would instantiate the delegate in your Activity and pass `this` as the LifecycleOwner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the Google documentation said about it:

> A LifecycleScope is defined for each Lifecycle object. Any coroutine launched in this scope is canceled when the Lifecycle is destroyed. You can access the CoroutineScope of the Lifecycle either via lifecycle.coroutineScope or lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope properties.

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        // Your code here
    }
```

Here the source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines