# Launching Lifecycle and calling Kotlin suspend function from Java file

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to integrate Google's TensorflowLite Pose Estimation Model in my project, however the [demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/pose_estimation/android) they provided is only written in Kotlin. I've never worked with Kotlin before, and the rest of my project is implemented in Java, so I'm trying to re-write the code at least in their `MainActivity` [(link)](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/pose_estimation/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/poseestimation/MainActivity.kt) into Java code. However, I'm having problem with this line of code that uses `lifecycleScope`, which was a concept only introduced in Kotlin:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    cameraSource?.initCamera()
}
```

I tried [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483062/what-scope-should-i-use-when-calling-a-suspended-function-from-a-java-activity) and re-write that line in my `MainActivity` as:

```
initCameraAsync(this);
```

while adding this to the file `CameraSource.kt` (the Kotlin file that has `initCamera()`)

```
fun initCameraAsync(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) {
    lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        initCamera()
    }
}
```

However, it still not work and the Camera failed to launch. I'm very new to this, so can someone give me some explanation of what might have gone wrong, and shed some light on how I might fix this? Thank you!

Comment: use only lifecycleScope and remove lifecycleOwner. in lifecycleScope, coroutines launched within the activity also die when the activity dies.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Have you checked which parts of your code get executed by adding [logging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)?